# UIButton text alignment centre different in iOS6 & iOS7

Tags: uibutton

I have set the below alignment properties but the text with the image centre align in iOS6 where as it centre aligns to pixel perfection in iOS7

```
beginNowButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
[beginNowButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
beginNowButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
```

Any guess for the fix? you can note the alignment difference in the below image.

[image]